I have a problem in using pandas.read_csv() reads a big csv file
Using pandas.read_csv() for reading a csv file which is 7GB in size , it takes long time and consumes 40GB+ memory, and even consumes more.
I am running on a win PC have 48G memory.
sc_ge = pd.read_csv('matrix.csv', index_col=0)

the matrix.csv file I downloaded is from text
Gene expression matrix (csv)
I try to read the first several rows in this file, I found it has 45769 columns, so I generate a csv file which contains 8000 rows and 45769 rows random number, the file I generated is 6.75G in size which is closed to the matrix.csv.
I used the pandas.read_csv() to read the file I generated, it used tens of seconds and then I successfully read the file.
I also try to use the Dask to read the file.
sc_ge = dask.dataframe.read_csv('matrix.csv', sample=1000000)
sc_ge = sc_ge.computI()

the compute() function has the similar phenomena as the pandas.read_csv()
So, why I cant read matrix.csv successfully? or is there other way I can get the dataframe of this csv file?
